# Is my chili plant infected?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, pests, chili

I have a 50 days old chili plant in the balcony. Yesterday I noticed some white formations on it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not sure if my plant is infected by some pest.

What do you think this is? And how can I deal with this and save the plant.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit hard to tell since I think the last photo especially is showing water droplets. But it sure looks like mealy bugs. They are a problem, but not that hard to control. If you want "green" solutions to this bug, here is a good link...otherwise, there are lots of commercial products available, and plenty of advice both on the internet and at your local garden center for what to use.
https://www.planetnatural.com/pest-problem-solver/houseplant-pests/mealybug-control/